# Converting input of str numbers to list of int numbers doesn't work on Pycharm but does on IDLE?

Tags: python, pycharm, list-comprehension

Hello I'm trying to convert an input of string numbers e.g. >>>1 2 3 4 into a list of integers >>>[1, 2, 3, 4] with this line of code.

```py
list_of_numbers = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(list_of_numbers)
```

it works in IDLE but not Pycharm. I cannot find an alternative on stack-overflow. I've tried many variations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's working for me. Are you typing in the numbers on PyCharm?

Comment: In what way does it fail to work?  If there was an error message, we need to see it of course.

Comment: It was a syntax error. I've tried the main console and python console on Pycharm.

Comment: list_of_numbers = for i in input().split()
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax